# «ОПЕК+» — нужен ли пробел перед знаком «+»?

Tags: орфография, аббревиатуры, пробелы

"ОПЕК+" или "ОПЕК +" — как правильно: с пробелом или без?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Инициальные аббревиатуры пишутся прописными буквами: ООН, МИД, РФ.
**Точки или пробелы между буквами не ставятся**, но между двумя самостоятельно употребляющимися аббревиатурами используется пробел: ИРЯ РАН, МИД РФ.
Пробел, конечно же, не нужен — между буквой и знаком в этом случае нет разницы.

*Это будет новая **ОПЕК+**, с новыми, российскими правилами игры, а не американскими; Мексика согласовала с **ОПЕК+** и США сокращение добычи нефти* (из статей).

[Как правильно употреблять аббревиатуры?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/60-rubric-91)

**Дополнение**
В качестве примеров можно привести и другие сокращения:
**НТВ+**, **ETV+**, **3+** (телеканалы); **Rh+** и **Rh–** (резус-фактор); **G+** (Google+).

Comment: Ну да, ну да!.. И здесь, признаюсь, я *прошляпилась* — со стремлением разобраться. (https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5&oq=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B8&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59i512j0i512l8.9429j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:3758b9ba,vid:9BnszYXpE9E)

Comment: Римма, а можно узнать, в чём заключается прошляпничество? По ссылке нет информации о знаках и пробелах?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Тут вот какое дело, Саша: я просмотрела (после принятого ответа) вопросы нашего участника и поддержала его вопрос с рейтингом "-1", добавив комментарий (можете посмотреть: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462479/%d0%9b%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%bd-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-2020-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0). А *прошляпничество* заключалось в том (красивое и емкое словечко у нас получилось, правда?), что и *этот* вопрос я когда-то почему-то не отметила плюсиком. Вчера исправилась.

Comment: А, понятно. Дык всё-таки, в "грамотной" статье нет ответа на вопрос... // А *doom1* никак не отреагировал на то сообщение. Может, надо через @? Или лучше под вопросом – тогда увидит.

Comment: Не знаю, Сашечка, может и надо. Подождем. Репутация ведь повысилась — пусть взыграет любопытство! P. S. "Грамотный" ответ все-таки есть: *точки или пробелы между буквами не ставятся...* (ООН, МИД, ОПЕК, РАН...) А плюсик нельзя отнести к самостоятельным аббревиатурам, это — знак (посчитаем за отдельную букву).