# «Локдаун» стало (или стал) словом 2020 года?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование

Как правильно?
*«Локдаун» стало словом 2020 года.

«Локдаун» стал словом 2020 года.*

Или то и другое неверно и надо обязательно добавить слово "слово"?
*Слово «локдаун» стало словом 2020 года.*

Comment: Это британские лингвисты назвали lockdown (строгая изоляция) словом года. Так что слово английское, а не русское.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**«Локдаун» стал словом 2020 года.**.
*Локдаун* — подлежащее, *стал* — сказуемое.

**Слово «локдаун» стало словом 2020 года.**
*Слово* — подлежащее, *стало* — сказуемое, *локдаун* — приложение.

Во избежание повтора можно написать так:
**Слово «локдаун» стало самым особенным** (главным, распространенным, необычным, употребляемым, используемым, растиражированным) **в 2020 году.**

[Согласование сказуемого с подлежащим](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091268.html)
[О слове «локдаун»](https://yandex.ru/news/instory/Slovar_Collins_priznal_lokdaun_slovom_2020_goda--01531b1da8bc9fba626f66a6a74cc8f6?persistent_id=118844394)

Comment: Поддержу Ваш вопрос (а то "минус один" — это как-то даже неприлично для вашего "формата"; извините, только увидела). P. S. Но одновременно я обнаружила, что из 41 вопроса Вы приняли (то есть посчитали наиболее полезным или решающим вашу проблему) только четыре. Думаю, что это не есть здо́рово, правильно. Мне кажется, что *можно уже ж* выбрать достойные ответы — хотя бы часть.